# Writing loops in R - Taking values from column and assigning it to a number

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataset called sample_data that consists of x column witch has 100 values. I want to use all 100 values and give them numbers from 1:100. One approach is written below, but in this case, I would need to make 100 lines of code.

I need some loop that will go through all columns and assign numbers for each value from 1 to 100.

```
sample_data %>% 
  mutate(example = case_when
         (x == "red" ~ 1,
          x == "blue" ~ 2,
          x == "green" ~ 3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the data you're intending to use as per a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform it to a factor and then to numeric. Like this:

```
z = mtcars
z$example_1 = as.numeric(as.factor(z$mpg))
```

Or with dplyr:

```
z %>% 
  mutate(example_2 = as.numeric(as.factor(mpg)))
```

Result:

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb example_1 example_2
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4        16        16
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4        16        16
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1        19        19
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1        17        17
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2        13        13
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1        12        12
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4         3         3
```

Comment: Great, that worked, so simple. Thank you so much!